# How to run MAUI exe from WindowsApps folder

Tags: maui

When I click on MAUI exe file the MAUI application does not open and I am getting the two different error. Please check below error screenshot.

[This is first error of MAUI application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trn58.png)

[This is second error of MAUI application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXXVR.png)

Comment: This question has already been asked, multiple times. Search for those discussions.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Maui generates packaged Windows apps which are launched from the Start menu on Windows. So you cannot initiate the packaged apps by splitting the package and executing the exe file.

As an alternative solution, you could still try to launch the app with an [execution alias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap5-executionalias).

Here are the detailed steps:

1.Please open(right click-> open with XML(Text) Editor with Encoding) the source code of `/Platforms/Windows/Package.appxmanifest` in your MAUI app, then reference the
namespace(`xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5"`) in the top of Package.appxmanifest, add the following code in the Application element.

```
<Extensions>
         <uap5:Extension Category="windows.appExecutionAlias">
                <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
                    <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="MyApp.exe"/>
                </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
         </uap5:Extension>
 </Extensions>
```

2. Run the app from VS to deploy it locally.
3. Run the app from the command line `C:\> MyApp.exe`:

[image]

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Hi, @Alexandar May - MSFT, We tried the same but MAUI application does not launch if End user does not have access to the WindowsApps folder in C:\Program Files\