# How to open MAUI Application from WinForms Application

Tags: winforms, maui

I am working on WinForms app which I'm trying to open MAUI application from WinForms application.

So, I'm wondering if it's possible to programmatically open a MAUI application from within a WinForms app?

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start a process from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c)

Comment: Whether the other process is MAUI, also Winforms, native or whatever is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: @PMF, I'm getting Win32Exception (0x80004005) "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation

Comment: That won't work if your app is in a package as [Alexandar has already told you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76528289/16938087). How are you deploying your app?

Comment: @GauravSharma can you post the exception and the code you are running in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maui proejct on the windows will be packaged by the MSIX Application Packager. You can add the following code below `</uap:VisualElements>` in the **/Platforms/Windows/Package.appxmanifest**:

```
xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5"
     .....
     .....
</uap:VisualElements>
       <Extensions>
                    <uap5:Extension
                                Category="windows.appExecutionAlias"
                                Executable="MauiAppTest.exe"
                                EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
                          <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
                                <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="MyApp.exe" />
                          </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
                    </uap5:Extension>
              </Extensions>
```

And then, you can use the `Process.Start("MyApp.exe");` to start the maui app in the WinForms Application.

Comment: Which line caused this error? @GauravSharma

Comment: Can you show the details in the `Package.appxmanifest`? @GauravSharma

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm able to open MAUI Application from WinForms Application.

Comment: Hi, @Liyun Zhang - MSFT, We tried the same but MAUI application does not launch if End user does not have access to the WindowsApps folder in C:\Program Files\

Comment: Sorry for I have no idea about this. @GauravSharma